# How to handle MongoDb concurrency update

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, concurrency, updates

I am using spring boot & MongoRepository. I am facing issue with concurrent process trying to update & read from database .

[image]

This is my usecase :

I am running my service on multiple instances & my service can accept kafka messages to process. As per the image attached,  i receive response 1 & response 2 & my service receive them & update response to mongo db. There is a possibility after mongo update i check if all the response available if true then proceed.

```
if(allResponseAvailabe){
   //Execute, this can happen 2 times.
}
```

How can i avoid this block to execute 2 times? Is there any way to lock or something ?